# login intercepter do not work in spring

Tags: spring

all. i was using spring4 in my project. and add and interceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter, then overwrite prehandle method. but i found it does not work when i was doing spring mock test.
i have configure it in springmvc-servlet.xml , like this:

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.suerpay.common.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

and here is code of LoginInteceptor:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Autowired
LoginServiceRedis loginServiceRedis;
@Autowired
UserServiceDB userServiceDB;
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    logger.info("start login interceptor");
    if (isLoginRequired(handler)) {
        String ticket = request.getHeader(GlobalConstants.TICKET_HEADER);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(ticket)) {
            throw new UnAuthorizedException(ResultCodeConstants.USER_NOT_LOGIN);
        }
        String userName = loginServiceRedis.getUserNameByTicket(ticket);
        Long userId = userServiceDB.getUserIdByName(userName);
        if (null == userId) {
            throw new         UnAuthorizedException(ResultCodeConstants.USER_NOT_LOGIN);
        }
        ThreadContextHolder.setCurrentUserId(userId);
    }
    logger.info("finish login interceptor");
    return true;
}

private boolean isLoginRequired(Object handler) {
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
    LoginRequired loginRequired = method.getAnnotation(LoginRequired.class);
    if (null != loginRequired) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

i think i have do everything , but just can not get into breakpoint.
who can tell me why?:(